# React-native change stack navigator title based on what is selected from nested drawer navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a drawer navigator nested inside a stack navigator like so

```
const DrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={'home'} size={25} />
        )
    },
  },
  Customers: {
    screen: Customers,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Customers',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={'account-switch'} size={25} />
        )
    },
  },
}, {
  drawerPosition: 'right',
})

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen : DrawerNavigation,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: navigation.state.routeName, // Always 'Home'
    }),
  },
})
```

This gave me the layout I desired, with a "title bar" that displays on both IOS and android, and makes the drawer navigation the main method of navigating the application. However, I would like the title prop for the stack navigator to display the name of whatever screen is selected from the drawer navigator rather than a static string. Is this possible with this current setup? Perhaps this is the incorrect approach - I am new to react-native's navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add title for each screen in the navigationOptions for each screen.

```
const DrawerNavigation = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      title: 'Home, sweet home!' // <=== add this
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={'home'} size={25} />
        )
    },
  },
  Customers: {
    screen: Customers,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Customers',
      title: 'Dear customers', // <=== and this
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={'account-switch'} size={25} />
        )
    },
  },
}, {
  drawerPosition: 'right',
})

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen : DrawerNavigation,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: navigation.state.routeName, // <=== remove this
    }),
  },
})
```

Also, you can set title on each screen component, more details [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers#Setting-the-Header-Title)

Comment: Putting title in navigation options inside the drawer itself did not work. I have a feeling the link you sent is the way to go, but do you know how to make it work when declaring your components as `const myClass = React.CreateClass` instead of `class MyClass extends Component`

Comment: Actually I just switched one of my classes from using `const MyClass = React.createClass` to `class MyClass extends Component` declaration and was able to add navigation options but it still didn't change the title

Comment: You should also remove title from StackNavigator, with `Home` screen